# When taking level 1 harm, do all rolls have less effect?

Tags: blades-in-the-dark

When taking level 1 harm, do all rolls have less effect? Or only when it applies to the narrative action?

For example: I have Bruised Arm as a level 1 harm. I want to bribe a Bluecoat to let us into a warehouse full of confiscated drugs. Do I roll with unaltered effect, or with one tier lower effect because of the bruised arm?

Looking for an answer rules as written.

Answer (score 7):

### No

You suffer the reduced effect or -1d penalty only if the harm applies to the situation:

> Your character suffers the penalty indicated at the end of the row if any or all harm recorded in that row applies to the situation at hand.

This is true for lesser or moderate harm. Severe harm renders the character incapacitated:

> When you’re impaired by harm in the top row (severe harm, level 3), your character is incapacitated and can’t do anything

See https://bladesinthedark.com/consequences-harm for more info.